# 3G video upload issue

Tags: android

I am trying to upload a video to server using my android device. 
I m using HTTP post request to post the data.
It normally works fine when using wi-fi connection. But as soon as i switch to 3g it doesn't get uploaded. i can see the progress bar (which i display while upload is in progress) but for a long time and finally if left for sometime then application hangs. Is there any solution to fix this issue. Please reply.

Comment: This may be beyond what is reasonable for the network you are using.  Can you monitor the transfer at the server?  In what specific way does the application hang?  Perhaps you should do the transfer in multiple smaller pieces and put them back together at the server - this may make it easier to resume if one chunk fails.